# Не работает простой запрос

Tags: jquery

Вот не пашет и все

```
 val = $(this).attr('data-id');

$('#field-type_rooms [value='+val+']').show();
```

Comment: полный код в студию. ах да, попробуй написать без пробелов, вот так $('#field-type_rooms[value='+val+']').show();

Comment: вот так не пашет 
val = 1;
$('#field-type_rooms option [value='+val+']').show();

и близко и далеко не как.. не понятно как вставить перменную

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  val = 1;
  $('input[item="'+val+'"]').hide(); // уберите пробел и значение в кавычки
});
```

[пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/ywMAm/6/)